# How can I prevent vncserver from crashing when I start it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, vnc-server

I have an `Ubuntu 16.04` droplet on `DigitalOcean` and I'm trying to set up remote desktop capabilities for it.  I followed these instructions through Step 2.  However, when I start the `VNC server` using the `vncserver` command, it goes haywire and bogs down the server until it crashes.  Here are excerpts from the log file:

```
19/12/17 23:47:52 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
19/12/17 23:47:52 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
19/12/17 23:47:52 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
19/12/17 23:47:52 All Rights Reserved.
19/12/17 23:47:52 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
19/12/17 23:47:52 Desktop name 'X' (thoughtful:1)
19/12/17 23:47:52 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
19/12/17 23:47:52 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/home/epoirier/.vnc/xstartup: 1: /home/epoirier/.vnc/xstartup: Cannot fork
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable
xrdb: cannot run '/usr/bin/cpp -P  -DHOST=thoughtful -DSERVERHOST=thoughtful -DSRVR_thoughtful -DDISPLAY_NUM=1 -DCLIENTHOST=thoughtful -DCLNT_thoughtful -DVERSION=11 -DREVISION=0 -DVENDOR="AT&T Laboratories Cambridge" -DVNDR_AT_T_Laboratories_Cambridge -DRELEASE=3332 -DNUM_SCREENS=1 -DEXT_XC_MISC -DEXT_SYNC -DEXT_MIT_SUNDRY_NONSTANDARD -DEXT_BIG_REQUESTS -DEXT_XTEST -DEXT_MIT_SHM -DEXT_SHAPE -DSCREEN_NUM=0 -DWIDTH=1024 -DHEIGHT=768 -DX_RESOLUTION=2951 -DY_RESOLUTION=2954 -DPLANES=24 -DBITS_PER_RGB=8 -DCLASS="TrueColor" -DCLASS_TrueColor=34 -DCOLOR -DCLASS_TrueColor_24=34 /home/epoirier/.Xresources'
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable
xrdb: cannot run '/usr/bin/cpp -P  -DHOST=thoughtful -DSERVERHOST=thoughtful -DSRVR_thoughtful -DDISPLAY_NUM=1 -DCLIENTHOST=thoughtful -DCLNT_thoughtful -DVERSION=11 -DREVISION=0 -DVENDOR="AT&T Laboratories Cambridge" -DVNDR_AT_T_Laboratories_Cambridge -DRELEASE=3332 -DNUM_SCREENS=1 -DEXT_XC_MISC -DEXT_SYNC -DEXT_MIT_SUNDRY_NONSTANDARD -DEXT_BIG_REQUESTS -DEXT_XTEST -DEXT_MIT_SHM -DEXT_SHAPE -DSCREEN_NUM=0 -DWIDTH=1024 -DHEIGHT=768 -DX_RESOLUTION=2951 -DY_RESOLUTION=2954 -DPLANES=24 -DBITS_PER_RGB=8 -DCLASS="TrueColor" -DCLASS_TrueColor=34 -DCOLOR -DCLASS_TrueColor_24=34 /home/epoirier/.Xresources'
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: 8: /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: Cannot fork
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: 8: /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: Cannot fork
cpp: error: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
sh: 1: Cannot fork
```

This is the beginning of the log and it descends into more chaos from here with many different `"Cannot fork"` warnings.  Nothing from the command line indicates that something is going wrong when starting the `VNC` server.  Anyone have any ideas on what's going wrong here?

Comment: Take a look at the [Archlinux Wiki - vncserver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running out of file descriptors for the user running that process.

Check what is the current limit with `ulimit -n` and change accordingly.